# Accessing POST query parameters from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've got a webhook coming in from a payment processor (I think HTTPS) on success (from Apache access log):

```
"POST /site/payment_webhook?clientAccnum=4444&&eventType=Success&eventGroupType=Subscription HTTP/1.1" 302 -                                                   "
```

My webhook action has:

```
if(   $this->request->query['eventType']==="Success"
   || $this->params['url']['eventType'] === "Success"
           ){
    //update database table
}
```

This condition does not get executed.  I've run the action on my dev machine, just typing the webhook in my browser, and the database updates.  But on testing server it doesn't update the table at all.  (If there are null values, a table row is still added with null values, so I know if condition is not met).

Comment: Your post request from the payment processor seem to get a 302 redirect. Compare the request (in the logs) from the paymentprocessor and your browser request, and check for differences.

Comment: The source page protocol is irrelevant to your question.